# Why does createsuperuser only work with heroku run

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, heroku

I can create do the following command:

```
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

And it works fine. But when I just run

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I get this error.

How come it works with heroku but not my local app?

```
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Comment: The error message clearly says that your `DATABASES` setting is not correct in your local environment. We can't help much without the actual settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is some code works fine at one place (heroku) and fails at another (local).  This might be because:

1. Django version at local might be different from that at heroku. 
   Even if it is same, chances are there that and local have 1.x with a
   bug and heroku have 1.x after a bugfix.
2. Same problem with postgres and psycopg2
3. Check if your working directory is clean and your-branch is up to
   date with heroku/your-branch